# how change the text in \IEEEkeyword

Tags: ieeetran

IEEE papers have `\IEEEkeyword`  command, but for other use in other languages.
How change the text to "Index terms" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you're using the `IEEEtran` class. You can add `\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Some words}` to change that text to `Some words`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Some words}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
This, that.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also necessary when your conference offers both Word and LaTeX templates, and the Word one says "keywords" rather than "index terms", and the reviewers insist that that is the only correct thing to say..... ;-)